# Error handling with JQuery When

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I am using JQuery [when](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). The syntax looks like this:

```
$.when(
  // Get the HTML
  $.get("/feature/", function(html) {
    globalStore.html = html;
  }),

  // Get the CSS
  $.get("/assets/feature.css", function(css) {
    globalStore.css = css;
  }),

  // Get the JS
  $.getScript("/assets/feature.js")

).then(function() {

  // Add CSS to page
  $("<style />").html(globalStore.css).appendTo("head");

  // Add HTML to page
  $("body").append(globalStore.html);

});
```

My question

1. How can I do error handling when one of the call to the server results in exception (failure scenario) or error handling for any other scenario?
2. Since I am making Ajax request here, how can I define timeout period for the Ajax request?

Answer (score 3):

[deferred.then( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks )](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) can take a failure filter like

```
$.when(
  // Get the HTML
  $.get("/feature/", function(html) {
    globalStore.html = html;
  }),

  // Get the CSS
  $.get("/assets/feature.css", function(css) {
    globalStore.css = css;
  }),

  // Get the JS
  $.getScript("/assets/feature.js")

).then(function() {

  // Add CSS to page
  $("<style />").html(globalStore.css).appendTo("head");

  // Add HTML to page
  $("body").append(globalStore.html);

}, function(){
    //there is an exception in the request
});
```

To setup the timeout, you can use the `timeout` option.

You can use it either globally like

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 5000
})
```

or use `$.ajax()` instead of the short version `$.get()` with the `timeout` option

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I need to apply timeout period for individual request. `JQuery.ajaxSetup` will not help in this case.

Comment: @SharpCoder in that case you can use the second option I suggested

Comment: And if you `.done` instead of `.then`? How do you handle error? Doc does not mention anything: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the calls are async. When using:

```
    $.ajax({
          url: "file.php",
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          success: function(data) {

          }
    });
```

The call is synchronous.